# Get multiple values in an xml file

Tags: regex, linux, python-3.x

```
        <!-- someotherline -->
<add name="core" connectionString="user id=value1;password=value2;Data Source=datasource1.comapany.com;Database=databasename_compny" />
```

I need to grab the values in userid , password, source, database. Not all lines are in the same format.My desired result would be (username=value1,password=value2, DataSource=datasource1.comapany.com,Database=databasename_compny)

This regex seems little bit more complicated as it is more complicated. Please, explain your answer if possible.

I realised its better to loop through each line. Code I wrote so far

```
while read p || [[ -n $p ]]; do
  #echo $p
  if [[ $p =~ .*connectionString.* ]]; then
    echo $p
  fi
done <a.config
```

Now inside the if I have to grab the values.

Comment: is your container element (`<add>` in your example) always the same ? is it possible that you have multiple elements ?

Comment: no add is not constant. connectionString is constant. So, far the code I wrote is 
`
#!/bin/bash


while read p || [[ -n $p ]]; do
  #echo $p
  if [[ $p =~ .*connectionString.* ]]; then
    echo $p
  fi
done <a.xml`
Inside the if I somehow have to grab values.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use bash shell commands as `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, etc ?

Comment: Yes. I can use all those. I am on redhat 7.

Comment: Ok, writing a complete response I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this solution I am considering:

- Some lines can contain no data
- No semi-colon *;* is inside the data itself (nor field names)
- No equal sign *=* is inside the data itself (nor field names)

A possible solution for you problem would be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while read p || [[ -n $p ]]; do

  # 1. Only keep what is between the quotes after connectionString=
  filteredLine=`echo $p | sed -n -e 's/^.*connectionString="\(.\+\)".*$/\1/p'`;

  # 2. Ignore empty lines (that do not contain the expected data)
  if [ -z "$filteredLine" ]; then
    continue;
  fi;

  # 3. split each field on a line
  oneFieldByLine=`echo $filteredLine | sed -e 's/;/\r\n/g'`;

  # 4. For each field
  while IFS= read -r field; do

    # extract field name + field value
    fieldName=`echo $field | sed 's/=.*$//'`;
    fieldValue=`echo $field | sed 's/^[^=]*=//' | sed 's/[\r\n]//'`;

    # do stuff with it
    echo "'$fieldName' => '$fieldValue'";

  done < <(printf '%s\n' "$oneFieldByLine")

done <a.xml
```

#### Explanations

> General `sed` replacement syntax :
>
> - `sed 's/a/b/'` will replace what matches the regex `a` by the content of `b`

- **Step 1**

  - `-n` argument tells `sed` not to output if no match is found. In this case this is useful to ignore *useless* lines.
  - `^.*` - anything at the beginning of the line
  - `connectionString="` - literally *connectionString="*
  - `\(.\+\)"` - capturing group to *store* anything in before the closing quote *"*
  - `.*$"` - anything until the end of the line
  - `\1` tells sed to replace the whole match with only the capturing group (which contains only the data between the quotes)
  - `p` tells `sed` to print out the replacement
- **Step 3**

  - Replace `;` by `\r\n` ; it is equivalent to splitting by semi-colon because bash can loop over line breaks
- **Step 4 - field name**

  - Replaces literal `=` and the rest of the line with nothing (it removes it)
- **Step 4 - field value**

  - Replaces all the characters at the beginning that are not `=` (`[^=]` matches all but what is after the '^' symbol) until the equal symbol by nothing.
  - Another `sed` command removes the line breaks by replacing it with nothing.

Comment: excellent. I am trying to remove commented lines in the file.So, instead of done <a.xml I used done <$(cat a.config | sed '/<!--.*-->/d' | sed '/<!--/,/-->/d') but it is throwing ambiguous redirect error. Any idea why?

Comment: The redirect error could mean that you cannot redirect the shell command (`$(cat ... | sed ...`) into the while loop because a file is expected but I am not sure about it.

Comment: **update**: this solution seems to work for me: 
`done < <(cat ... | sed ...)`

Otherwise, my answer normally ignores comments and non-matching lines.

Comment: Sorry, last doubt. How would the logic change if connectionString is case-insensitive.

Comment: Never-mind. I added I at the end and it worked well.
filteredLine=`echo $p | sed -n -e 's/^.*connectionString="\(.\+\)".*$/\1/pI'`;